Custom format and align Databricks SQL results
My Azure Databricks SQL query outputs total number of products and total price aggregated by month. The values range from a few 100s to millions for different products. I want the count and sum to be formatted with 1000s separator and right aligned. Count needs to have only numbers and sum needs to be with 2 decimal positions.
When I use format_number(count(distinct product), 0) and format_number(sum(price), 2), the results get left aligned. I think it's because the formatting converts numbers into text and hence left align. I also tried lpad((format_number(count(distinct product), 0)), 50, ' ') and same with sum. But then the alignments are all over the place.
Would you please help to sort this out ? Thanks much in advance.

If you want this result :
+-------+------------------+---------------+
|month  |formatted_products|formatted_price|
+-------+------------------+---------------+
|2024-02|         3        |      81,700.50|
|2024-01|         2        |      25,400.50|
|2024-03|         2        |       3,550.00|
+-------+------------------+---------------+

you have to use this format :
formatted_df = (aggregated_df
                .withColumn("formatted_products", lpad(format_number(col("total_products"), 0), 10, ' '))
                .withColumn("formatted_price", lpad(format_number(col("total_price"), 2), 15, ' '))
                .select("month", "formatted_products", "formatted_price"))


Thank you for the reply. However, I am looking for an option to accommodate it in the SQL itself.
